# Implement iterator that does not consume

Tags: rust, iterator

I have this code, for learning purposes:

```
struct Fibonacci {
    curr: u32,
    next: u32,
}

impl Iterator for Fibonacci {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let current = self.curr;

        self.curr = self.next;
        self.next = current + self.next;
        Some(current)
    }
}

impl Fibonacci {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Fibonacci { curr: 0, next: 1 }
    }

    fn current(&self) -> u32 {
        self.curr
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("The first four terms of the Fibonacci sequence are: ");
    let fib = Fibonacci::new();
    for i in fib.take(4) {
        println!("> {}", i);
    }
    // println!("cur {}", fib.current()); // *fails*
   
}
```

Here `fib.take(4)` consumes the `fib` value, so the commented out `println` below the loop doing `fib.current()` fails , quite naturally, with:

```
    let fib = Fibonacci::new();
         --- move occurs because `fib` has type `Fibonacci`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    for i in fib.take(4) {
                  ------- `fib` moved due to this method call
...
     println!("cur {}", fib.current());
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move

note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `fib`
```

How would I implement the code above such that the Iterator does not consume it's value, and I can use the `fib` variable after the loop ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref):

> Borrows an iterator, rather than consuming it.
>
> This is useful to allow applying iterator adapters while still retaining ownership of the original iterator.

```
println!("The first four terms of the Fibonacci sequence are: ");
let mut fib = Fibonacci::new();
for i in fib.by_ref().take(4) {
    println!("> {}", i);
}
println!("cur {}", fib.current());
```

```
The first four terms of the Fibonacci sequence are: 
> 0
> 1
> 1
> 2
cur 3
```

Comment: Or borrow `(&mut fib).take(4)`, which is essentially the same.